# phpLDAP filter dn & uid

Tags: php, authentication, openldap, ldap-query, ldapconnection

I have the following code:

```
if($_POST){

$ldap['user'] = $_POST['user'];
$ldap['pass'] = $_POST['pass'];
$ldap['conn'] = ldap_connect('my_ip')
or die("Could not connect to {'my_ip'}" );

ldap_set_option($ldap['conn'], LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($ldap['conn'], LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
$ldap['bind'] = @ldap_bind($ldap['conn'], $ldap['user'], $ldap['pass']);

if( !$ldap['bind'] )
{
echo ldap_error( $ldap['conn'] );
exit;
}
```

And a login form:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<p>
User Name:
<input type="text" name="user" >
Password:
<input type="password" name="pass" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</p>
</form>
```

Everything works fine, except, in order to work, I have to input the entire DN as username. Like this: `uid=user,ou=people,dc=my-domain,dc=com`.

What I want is to set the base dn and get the uid as the necessary username.

I tried setting `$basedn = 'dc=mydomain,dc=de'and $filter="uid"` with `$sr=ldap_search($filter, $basedn);` but I don't know how to bind it to my login $_POST variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After very thoroughly searching through the other questions, I found a duplicate with the appropriate answer.

[LDAP bind using POST variable for UID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16520993/ldap-bind-using-post-variable-for-uid?rq=1)

So, according to zenlord:

```
$ldap['user']  = 'uid =' . $_POST['user'] . ',ou=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX';
```

or

```
$ldap['user']  = "uid =$_POST['user'],ou=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX,dc=XXX";
```